# Flutter http post request gives status code 401

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am using API to verify phone number provided by user.... on postman api give perfect response and give OTP code in response but in flutter status code 401 is returned
here is my code

```
 Future verifyPhone(String phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      String token = "528724967b62c6c9e546aeaee1b57e234991ad98";
      var body = <String, String>{};
      body['user_number'] = phoneNumber;
      var url = Uri.parse(ApiKeys.phoneVerifyApiKey);
      var response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "authentication": "Bearer $token"
        },
        body: body,
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Code sent");
      } else {
        print("Failed to send code");
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
    }
notifyListeners();
  }
```

instead of "code sent" i get "failed to send code" and status code 401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT
You can send form request this way

```
  Future verifyPhone(String phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      String token = "528724967b62c6c9e546aeaee1b57e234991ad98";
      var body = <String, String>{};
      body['user_number'] = phoneNumber;
      var url = Uri.parse(ApiKeys.phoneVerifyApiKey);
      
      var headers  ={
        
         "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "authentication": "Bearer $token"
      };
      
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url)
    ..headers.addAll(headers) 
    ..fields.addAll(body);
    
      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
  
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Code sent");
      } else {
        print("Failed to send code");
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
    }
notifyListeners();
  }
```

EDIT

To access :

```
var  _data = jsonDecode(response);
  
  var list = _data["data"];
  
  print(list[0]['otp_code']);
```

Comment: API is accepting form-data not JSON... that's why i cannot encode it

Comment: @UsmanHafeez : Anser is updated please check

Comment: still same issue :(

Comment: is is correct  url that you are going tyo hit   ApiKeys.phoneVerifyApiKey ?

Comment: yes it's correct i checked twice

Comment: you can remove this :   "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
or you can share request which is working in postman  . just a screenshot by hiding url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247334/discussion-between-usman-hafeez-and-hardik-mehta).

Comment: thank you sooooooo much i got my problem solved with the way you told me.... Thanks again :)

Comment: Please accept or upvote my answer if its work for you then

Comment: Okay sure i'll....

Comment: one more thing please.. how can i print response.body?  i am getting this message The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'StreamedResponse'.

Comment: respinse.stream is printing full response but i only need otp code from response...

Comment: Check edited answer please. you will get idea

Comment: response is like this {
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "otp_code": 812292
        }
    ]
}

Comment: but when i access it like this : print(data["data"]["otp_code"]); it says type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'... but when i print(data["data"] it prints full response including otp code

Comment: Check edited answer please  @UsmanHafeez

Comment: didn't get your question. can you create another question in stackoverflow  ? here its comments section taking too long

Comment: Can i get your email please?